# Invoke action after bean is created by Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I want to execute custom action after a Spring container will create the instance of some type of bean e.g. bean which is annotated with `@MyAnnotation`.
I do not want to use `@PostConstruct`no `init-method` because the required custom action should not be saved in created bean but outside of it.

So I hope that Spring has some interface with method like `newBeanCreated` and I hope that I wolud implement it like this:

```
public void newBeanCreated(Object newObjReference){
  if (newObjReference.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class)) {
     System.out.println("Here I am!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you ar looking for the [BeanPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) interface.

Answer (score 2):

**Below example might also help you:**

```
      import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
      import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;

      public class MyBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

      public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String  beanName) throws BeansException {
          return bean;  
      }

      public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
      if(beanName.equals("com.x.y.z")) //Fully Classified Bean Class Name
      {
           //You can place your logic here
      }
      return bean;
   }   
}
```